# What does it mean share project in STS?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, maven

I have imported project with Maven. But Subclipse didn't recognize that project already in SVN (I don't see pictogram barrel). For team in context menu I see 2 options:

```
Apply path
Share project
```

Which one I must select? In SVN repository there is already project made by other persons.
And I also made checkout by Tortoise. So I need only to recognize SVN local repository by STS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the project should make it detect that .svn directories already exist, and should propose you to keep these files and use the information they contain to establish the SVN configuration of the project.

Comment: What does mean Apply path? Which path? Apply for what?

Comment: It's Apply pat**c**h. It allows taking a patch file and applying it on your source code.

Answer (score 1):

svn is a versionmanagement system. if you got old code and someone released a newer version you can apply a patch. you can share your project on cvs svn and git. like github or google project.

you need to go to new svn repoository and select the one of your project. then you can checkout project as new project. maven is for dependencies, not for code manipulation